# Displaying full screen video on only 1 monitor

Tags: safari, youtube

I have a multiple monitor setup. I'd like to be able to play a video full screen on only one of them. It could be Quicktime or a Safari video (mostly Safari/YouTube). Is there any setting to control this at all? Right now the video takes over the screen and the others go black. (Have seen other older answers but no solutions recently.)

Answer (score -1):

Try to disable mirroring in System Preferences > Displays and move application which play video to the screen you want.